# How to split subarray and generate unique combinations

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
var arry = ['a','b','c','d',['l','o','p']];
```

I am trying to write a function which does give me the below output but failed

```
['a','b','c','d','l']
['a','b','c','d','o']
['a','b','c','d','p']
```

I have searched similar questions, but unable to find the right one.
can someone share some light on it?

Updates:
Sometimes we may have multiple sub array:

```
   var arry = ['a','b','c','d',['l','o','p'],[1,4]];
```

then

```
['a','b','c','d','l',1]
['a','b','c','d','o',1]
['a','b','c','d','p',1]
['a','b','c','d','l',4]
['a','b','c','d','o',4]
['a','b','c','d','p',4]
```

Comment: Is the subarray always the last element?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Eddie no, infact we may have multiple sub array sometimes

Comment: You might want to give example on the multiple sub array and what is your expected output

Comment: @mplungjan Yup Ive seen it. But the OP said There could be multiple sub arrays

Comment: @Eddie updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert single items to arrays and iterate them and take all combinations of the arrays.

```js
function getCombinations(array) {
    function iter(index, temp) {
        if (temp.length === iterables.length) {
            result.push(temp);
            return;
        }
        iterables[index].forEach(v => iter(index + 1, temp.concat(v)));
    }

    var iterables = array.map(a => Array.isArray(a) ? a: [a]),
        result = [];
        
    iter(0, []);
    return result;
}

var array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['l', 'o', 'p'], [1, 4]];

console.log(getCombinations(array).map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

Comment: I wrote a more readable script, then I made a small change and the chrome tab snapped :( - I do not grok recursion

Comment: That's awesome, Thank you so much Nina

Answer (score 1):

## ES6

You could also use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get the required result.

- First take all sub-array into one array
- Then after create combination of all that sub-array
- Then after you can `concat` all combination with you single array.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['l', 'o', 'p'],[1, 4]];

let result = arr.reduce((r, v) => {
  Array.isArray(v) ? r.subArr.push(v) : r.arr.push(v);
  return r;
  }, {arr: [],subArr: []});

let allCombination = (arr, subArr) => {
  return subArr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.reduce((res, value) => res.concat(val.map(mval => [].concat(arr, value, mval))), []));
}

console.log(allCombination(result.arr, result.subArr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```

---

You can also use [`generator function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function%2A) after the creating sub-array to create combination and `concat` with you single array.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', ['l', 'o', 'p'],[1, 4]];

let result = arr.reduce((r, v) => {
  Array.isArray(v) ? r.subArr.push(v) : r.arr.push(v);
  return r;
  }, {arr: [],subArr: []});

function* combination(head, ...tail) {
  let remainder = tail.length ? combination(...tail) : [[]];
  for (let r of remainder) for (let h of head) yield [h, ...r];
}

for (let val of combination(...result.subArr)) {
  console.log(result.arr.concat(val));
}
```

```css
    .as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```